# Traversing the DOM to toggle a panel footer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm new to jquery and I'm trying to figure out how to traverse the dom in order to toggle the collapse option on panel footers? Any pointers?

```
<div id="colDealDiv" class="row col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 colDiv">
   <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
         <p>Retail &amp; Services</p></div>
      <div class="panel-body">
       <div id="thumbnailDealDiv" class="thumbnail">
       <div id="captionDealDiv" class="caption">
         <p>$35 -- 'Best of NY': Painting Parties at City Bars, Reg. $65</p>
         <p>Paint Nite</p>
         <p>New York</p>
         <p>NY</p><img src="https://api.sqoot.com/v2/deals/4344628/image?api_key=demo" class="img-thumbnail">
         <button class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse"></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
       <div class="panel-footer collapse">
         <p>46% off at Paint Nite</p>
         <p>35</p>
         <p>2016-05-24T13:00:00Z</p>              
   </div>
</div>
```

```
  $(".panel").on("click", ".btn-info", function() {
    $(this).parent().next(".panel-footer").collapse("toggle");
});
```